# session_destroy() not working in PHP

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I am getting the error:

```
Warning: session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Session object destruction failed in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 20
Failed to destroy session. Please reload the page.
```

Which is coming from my timeout code, but it is only happening on one client, others are working fine.

I have tried deleting all of the session files off of the server, but it will not let me destroy the particular session that is causing the error. It is telling me that the file is in use by CMD.exe.

Any ideas on how to fix this, what is causing this, or how to stop cmd.exe from using the file?

Comment: I have session_destroy() on line 20. It has worked fine for the past 2 years and nothing has changed in that file. Also, it is working on all other clients, so I believe it is a windows issue more than a PHP issue.

Comment: if it is used by cmd.exe some service is accessing it. I would guess, rebooting the server will solve the problem

Comment: Have you tried killing all instances of `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Oh wow, just checked running processes for all users... There are about 200 instances of cmd.exe running. Jeez

Comment: @Ethan Prob best to find the cause of that ;)

Comment: I found a php script that was calling shell_exec() and running a bat file that did not close out cmd. I believe that was the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just restarting the server. Not the ideal fix, but it worked.

Comment: It may not be idea, but sometimes it is the correct answer. (particularly when the server is Windows-based)